# Connect to existing session with NoMachine without activating monitor/keyboard

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, nomachine

I want to remotely connect to the same desktop session that I have already running on my work computer from home so that I don't have to shut down everything and restart in order to get going. However, I've seen that when my coworkers shadow their session remotely their computer is unlocked and we can all watch what they do and jiggle the mouse around and generally mess with them.

Is there a way to shadow the existing session remotely without activating the local monitor and keyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the blank screen feature:

Supporting the blank screen feature during a remote desktop session
https://www.nomachine.com/FR09I02610

If you're connecting to a Linux host, the Workstation for Linux support virtual desktop, so running a virtual desktop will mean that nothing is shown on the screen.

https://www.nomachine.com/forums/topic/how-to-hide-display-output-on-remote-machine#post-5734

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote your answer as well but I don't have enough points.

Comment: Here are the instructions for the feature: https://www.nomachine.com/AR07M00851&an=blank%20screen

Comment: Side note: I'm quite surprised this isn't default behaviour. I was really surprised to learn that my remote desktop sessions had been completely open to any passers by.